# How to retrieve last autoincremented value in MS-Access like @@Identity in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, identity-column

I want to retrieve identity column value in ms access from an autoincremented column.
Basically i m running a transaction in which i have to write two insert queries. 2nd query will be containing autoincremented value that was generated from query 1. how can i do that ?

Comment: Why didn't you actually just attempt SELECT @@IDENTITY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, Microsoft Access 2000 or later does support the @@IDENTITY property to retrieve the value of an Autonumber field after an INSERT

Source: [Retrieving Identity or Autonumber Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0(VS.71).aspx)

**EDIT**: As noted by @[David-W-Fenton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9787/david-w-fenton), you'll also need to use `Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider` (this is also described into that previous document)

Comment: It's Jet 4, not Access 2000, that supports SELECT @@IDENTITY.

Comment: @David,that referenced document talks about a combination of Access 2000 and Jet 4.0; I'd update this answer to empathize this aspect.

Comment: Debug.Print CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select @@identity")(0)              works in the debug window..

Comment: Not sure what's meant by needing to use Jet 4 OLE DB Provider -- it works just fine with DAO against Jet 4 and forward. I use it all the time, and I've never written more than a couple hundred lines of ADO/OLEDB code in my entire Access programming career.

Comment: @Rubens Farias: "Combination of A2000 and Jet 4.0" -- er, A2000 used Jet 4 by default, so that would be expected. Not sure what you're trying to say, but the assertion that SELECT @@IDENTITY in Jet is supported only if you use ADO/OLEDB (or SQL 92 mode, which you don't mention) is simply incorrect. Please correct your post.

Comment: @David, refer to link document and, please, help me to fix this post, ty!

Comment: The cited article is wrong. Try it and see -- SELECT @@IDENTITY works with DAO 3.6 and Jet 4.0.

Comment: This is a "Link only answer"