# How to insert into two different tables that are linked together in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have two tables like this


First Tasble

colID  | Col1  | Col..

Second table

ColID | ColIDFirstTable | Col..

I want that when I click a button first to insert in First table from my form, and after inserting in first table to take the ID of first table that is primary key and to insert in the second table in second column.
Something  like this

```
 CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO FirstTable(Col2,vol3)" VALUES  ('" & Txt1.Value & "', '" &Txt2.Value & "')"

  CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO SecondTabkle(Col2,vol3)" VALUES  ('" & IDFirstTbale& "', '" &Txt5.Value & "')"
```

But I Don't  know how to take the ID from First Table and to insert in second Table..

Thanx in advance

Comment: please have look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533283/how-do-we-get-last-inserted-record-in-msaccess-query

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942781/select-identity-not-scoped-by-db-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the examples I sent in the comments, your code can look like this:

```
Dim db1 As DAO.Database
Dim id1 As Long

Set db1 = CurrentDb

db1.Execute "INSERT INTO FirstTable(Col2,vol3) VALUES ('" & Txt1.Value & "', '" & Txt2.Value & "')", dbFailOnError

id1 = db1.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)

db1.Execute "INSERT INTO SecondTable(Col2,vol3) VALUES (" & id1 & ", '" & Txt5.Value & "')", dbFailOnError
```