# Cannot view or insert MS Access oledb via VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I was trying to insert values to the MS ACCESS DB but I can't insert any data to ACCESS. I have CustomerID as primary key with auto increment. After running the code it always gives me  Total Customers  0* Please help me figure out whats going wrong here!

This is my code

```
Public Const settings As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                                  "Data Source=Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                                  "Data Source=C:\Users\sha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Assign2_24\Assign2_24\db24.accdb;"

Dim vConnStr As New OleDbConnection(settings)

If vboo = "" Then

        Try
             vConnStr.Open()
            Dim vSQL As String = "Insert into Customer "
            vSQL = vSQL & " (FirstName, LastName, Telephone, Email)"
            vSQL = vSQL & " Values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
            Dim cmd As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(vSQL, vConnStr)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cusFName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", cusLName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cusTP)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", cusEmail)


            Dim vRowsUpdated As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved to the system" & vRowsUpdated)


            '*************************************** Retrieve the CusID that have inserted *******************************

            Dim vSQL2 As String = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
            Dim cmd2 As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(vSQL2, vConnStr)

            Dim vCusId As Integer = CInt(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())
            MessageBox.Show("*** ID: " & vCusId)

            'Dim vCusId As Integer = CInt(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())
            'MessageBox.Show("*** ID: " & vCusId)

            Dim vSQL3 As String = "Select count (*) from Customer"
            Dim cmd3 As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd3.CommandText = vSQL3

            Dim vCount3 As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            MessageBox.Show("***** Total Customers " & vCount3)



        Catch ex As Data.Odbc.OdbcException

            Dim vErMsg As String = " *** Error occured while registering the customer ***"
            vErMsg = vErMsg & ex.ErrorCode & "***" & ex.Message & "***"


        Finally
            vConnStr.Close()
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no LAST_INSERT_ID functionality in MSAccess. Try instead

```
"SELECT @@IDENTITY"
```

Said that, I strongly suggest to change you orginal command to use a parameterized query. It always a safe approach to database commands because you don't have to worry to correctly quote your strings, numerics and dates, but, most important, you avoid Sql Injection

```
Dim vSQL As String = "Insert into Customer "
vSQL = vSQL & " (FirstName, LastName, Telephone, Email)"
vSQL = vSQL & " Values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
Dim cmd As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(vSQL, vConnStr)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cusFName)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", cusLName)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cusTP)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", cusEmail)
```

As a side note. You are catching an ODBC exception, but your code uses OleDb. (leftover from previous version?)

**GOT IT**

This line executes the first query, not the second one

```
Dim cmd2 As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(vSQL2, vConnStr)
                                            ^
```

and finally use the cmd3 instance to count the customers

```
Dim vCount3 As Integer = cmd3.ExecuteScalar()
MessageBox.Show("***** Total Customers " & vCount3)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Tried your code still the same ;(

Comment: There is a typo in your second query. You pass again the first sql instead of `SELECT @@IDENTITY`

Comment: Hi Steve Thanks for bringing that up now I got the vCusId part working ;) But the main issue is it doesn't  store in my database! when I run    Dim vCusId As Integer = CInt(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())
            MessageBox.Show("***** Total Customers " & vCusId)                        it throws me ***** Total Customers 0 and nothing is on the db

Comment: Try with  `Dim vCusId = cmd2.ExecuteScalar()` (not forcing the output of ExecuteScalar to integer. If you haven't inserted the record the vRowsUpdated should be zero. What value do you have for vRowsUpdated ?

Comment: I got the vCusId part working ;)                                     But the main issue is it doesn't store in my database!

Comment: because you use cmd instead of cmd3

Comment: Oh dear... Got everything smoothly running now! (Feel like a silly head!! ;() Do u have any idea why my Access table in MS Access is still empty while I get the total customer = 89 ????

Comment: Probably you are not looking at the same database defined by your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article, [autoincremented-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082427/how-to-retrieve-last-autoincremented-value-in-ms-access-like-identity-in-sql-s), appearently it works different in 2000 or greater.

Also, I think you you have a problem with your variables. You are use vSQL with cmd but you also use vSQL with cmd2. So, when you do your `CInt(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())`, you are actually running your insert again.  Try grouping your stuff together so it is easier to follow, like this:

```
Dim vSQL As String = "  Insert into Customer "
vSQL = vSQL & " (FirstName, LastName, Telephone, Email)"
vSQL = vSQL & " Values ("
vSQL = vSQL & "'" & cusFName & "'"
vSQL = vSQL & "," & "'" & cusLName & "'"
vSQL = vSQL & "," & cusTP
vSQL = vSQL & "," & "'" & cusEmail & "'"
vSQL = vSQL & ");"

Dim cmd As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(vSQL, vConnStr)
Dim vRowsUpdated As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved to the system" & vRowsUpdated)

Dim vSQL2 As String = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"
Dim cmd2 As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(vSQL2, vConnStr)
Dim vCusId As Integer = CInt(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())
MessageBox.Show("*** ID: " & vCusId)
```

This will help so you can't use vSQL2 or cmd2 before they are declared and removing 1/2 of your possible errors.

Comment: Hi Steve Thanks for bringing that up now I got the vCusId part working ;) But the main issue is it doesn't  store in my database! when I run    Dim vCusId As Integer = CInt(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())
            MessageBox.Show("***** Total Customers " & vCusId)                        it throws me ***** Total Customers 0 and nothing is on the db

Comment: Assuming you did all the things mentioned in these comments and answers, I think you are missing the colon required by access. You have `vSQL = vSQL & " Values (?, ?, ?, ?)"` but it should be `vSQL = vSQL & " Values (?, ?, ?, ?);"`