# Creating new records in MSACCESS Table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am attempting to create a new record from vb.net to an msaccess table, which i am able to do, but i have to add in the next consecutive ID number for it to actually save.  For instance, if the next ID in the Access DB is 4, i have to type in 4 in the id textfield on my form.  Code below:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim sqlinsert As String
    ' We use the INSERT statement which tells our program to add the information  
    ' from the Forms Text fields into the Databases columns.   
    sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO Table1(Title, YearofFilm, Description, Field1, ID)" & _
    "VALUES(@Title, @YearofFilm, @Description, @Field1, @ID)"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con1)
    ' This assigns the values for our columns in the DataBase.   
    ' To ensure the correct values are written to the correct column  
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Title", TextBox1.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@YearofFilm", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Description", TextBox3.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Field1", TextBox4.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text)))
    ' This is what actually writes our changes to the DataBase.  
    ' You have to open the connection, execute the commands and  
    ' then close connection.  
    con1.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con1.Close()
    ' This are subs in Module1, to clear all the TextBoxes on the form  
    ' and refresh the DataGridView on the MainForm to show our new records.  
    ClearTextBox(Me)
    RefreshDGV()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

How can i tell textbox5 which is the ID field, to be the next number in the access db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Access database, show the structure of your table and change the ID field type from numeric to [AutoNumber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoNumber).

Now your code don't need to pass anything to Access because the number will be handled automatically from Access.

You could just add these lines to your code to get back the number assigned by Access to your field

```
Dim sqlinsert As String
sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO Table1(Title, YearofFilm, Description, Field1)" & _
            "VALUES(@Title, @YearofFilm, @Description, @Field1)"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con1)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Title", TextBox1.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@YearofFilm", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Description", TextBox3.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Field1", TextBox4.Text))
con1.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Parameters.Clear()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
Dim assignedID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
' Eventually
TextBox5.Text = assignedID.ToString
con1.Close()
......
```

See also 
[How to retrieve last autoincremented value in MS-Access like @@Identity in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082427/how-to-retrieve-last-autoincremented-value-in-ms-access-like-identity-in-sql-s)

Answer (score 0):

Create a SELECT statement to retrieve the Max number form the table and add one to it. I do not know VB.Net, so it should be something like.

```
maxQry = "SELECT Max(IDColumnName) As MaxID FROM theTableName;"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(maxQry, con1)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.HasRows Then
    While dr.Read()
        TextBox5.Text = dr("MaxID").ToString
    End While
End If
```

Unless the field is an AutoNumber type you do not have to worry about it at all.